# Where to define selectors with async pip in NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx

To take advantage of async pipe we should create a selector observable in the component class. However, everybody recommends using `ngOnInit()` to do so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    person$: Observable<Person>;
    constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.person$ = this.store.select(stateToCurrentPersonSelector);
    }
}
```

What if we define the selector observable outside of the `ngOnInit()` like the following snippet. It works perfectly fine:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    person$ = this.store.select(stateToCurrentPersonSelector);
    constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: What error are you facing? If you need an opinion I would say you don't required ngOnInit event at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of async pipe, there's no difference in term of performance.

> You might think it’s better to wait for ngOnInit() to trigger the
> fetch of products, but here’s the deal.
> Steams, unlike promises, are
> lazy.
> They don’t execute their logic until they're subscribed to.
> That means there is no difference to request timing for both
> approaches.

You can find more info about this from here:
https://twitter.com/realTomaszKula/status/1559258801261404166